# #Excel - How do I compare two columns of different length and extract the difference in a separate column?

Tags: excel

I have two columns, column A with 8000 records, column B with 115k records. I want to **compare A with B** (not all records in A exist in B), and **extract the difference in column C** (i.e, I want data from column A which is not there in column B).

I don't want to highlight them or whatever, I just want the difference for some other use. Tried various possibilities but ended up with C displaying all the values in A, without comparing with B. So frustrating! Help me if you can, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=0,1,"")
```

In **D2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A2)=0,1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down as far as column **A**.  In **C1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),D:D,0)),"")
```

and also copy down as far as **A**:

[image]

Column **D** is a helper column that marks the column **A** items that should be picked up.

Comment: I have the same scenario but I have lower case and upper case mixed up and wild card not working. Like I have PORTIA but it doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

Self explanatory,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1),"Found","Not Found")
```

[image]

Comment: Gowtham, I was able to comment it as "True" and "False", the thing is I want the "not found" data itself to be on column C. In your example, say 2 is "not found", I want that 2 to be in column C. Same goes with 4. At the end, I just want 2 and 4 to be in column C. Is there any way to extract like that? Thanks!

Comment: replace not found with `A1` in the formula